# Include path's working

Tags: php

I am setting up an old website on my development server and I have come across a few PHP error messages, they are as follows;

File path **/php/register_company.php**

> Warning: include(./_mrprivate/includes/dblogin.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in /Sites/Martin
>   James/_mrprivate/includes/dbaccess.php on line 29
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening './_mrprivate/includes/dblogin.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in /Sites/Martin
>   James/_mrprivate/includes/dbaccess.php on line 29
>
> Warning: include(./_mrprivate/includes/dbapplogin.php): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in /Sites/Martin
>   James/_mrprivate/includes/dbaccess.php on line 30
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening './_mrprivate/includes/dbapplogin.php' for 
>   inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in /Sites/Martin
>   James/_mrprivate/includes/dbaccess.php on line 30

I have played with the file paths but the error message have not changed in the slightest!

Comment: What is your question? Is there anything not clear with the error messages you posted? I also can recommend our error reference which often has some cool tips on common errors: [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456)

Comment: Where (what path) is the main PHP file that is including those files?

Comment: /php/register_company.php

Comment: Write your root path for an acceptable, or otherwise use full path with no `../`, read about `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and understand concepts of `php.net/getcwd`...

Comment: @BradHouston: Just a hint: having the dot `.` in the include path is normally not recommended. I did have it in the past but since I switched to the magic constants some years ago, I never needed it any longer. It's a burden to have in the include-path because PHP will look in many places if it's in there and it's normally not needed (can be a performance drain as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Warning: include(./_mrprivate/includes/dblogin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Sites/Martin James/_mrprivate/includes/dbaccess.php on line 29

Your code is trying to include

```
/Sites/Martin James/_mrprivate/includes/./_mrprivate/includes/dblogin.php
```

But I suspect you really want to include

```
/Sites/Martin James/_mrprivate/includes/dblogin.php
```

Don't change your include_path, either use the correct relative path (i.e. relative to the file containing the include/require directive) or an absolute path.

Comment: And because it is so useful: Remember, that `__DIR__ . '/../../path/to/my/file.php` is an absolute path :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have code like this:

```
include('./_mrprivate/includes/dblogin.php')
```

With your configured include path:

```
include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php'
```

You would not need to add the `.` in front anyway. However as this is often a cause of problems, it is way better to relate to the magic constants `__FILE__` and (PHP 5.3+) `__DIR__`:

```
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/_mrprivate/includes/dblogin.php');
```

Comment: Don't know exactly, but as far as I remember the leading `.` will make PHP ignoring the include path, because in fact it explicitly says "from _here_".

Comment: @KingCrunch: You remember right, I just verified what you said is correct because I wanted to know as well for sure. However that is only for `./`, not for `../` and not for `/` and not for `/./` (which looks like a sneaky secret move here). We should probably create a question for that with an answer.

Comment: Starting with a `/` usually means "Filesystem root" anyway :p But this shouldn't use the include neither, because ... yeah, it is bound to the filesystem root. I guess the "secret" is, that the include path only covers "really relative" paths, whereas `.` reflects the current working directory (which is "kind of" absolut) and `/` the root (which is really absolute).

Comment: Yes but the root is not taken into account actually, so writing `file.php` or `/file.php` will make PHP look into the include-path. Only writing `./file.php` won't.

Comment: Just tested it, it is not true: Actually the file is `/usr/share/peclcmd.php` and `include 'peclcmd.php';` works, but `include '/peclcmd.php';` fails. Test from within interactive shell (`php -a`) with standard include path on ubuntu `.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear`. Also imo everything else would be confusing anyway ;) Especially because everything starting with `/` is _the_ absolute path of all absolute paths :D

Answer (score 0):

Change the site name in database.. i'm not sure but it may be help you

Comment: The URL is not set in the database.